# How to activate the excel from where I run my vba but not by Windows(filename).activate

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook called `Book1` with VBA code that opens another workbook and gets data from it to add it to `Book1`.

In my code it is written that:

```
Windows("Book1.xlsm").Activate
```

When VBA gets back to the workbook where my code is starting, I want to make a reference to my workbook so that it won't matter whether the workbook will be named `Book2` or any other name and won't matter where it will be located. How can I do this please?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` always referes to the `Workbook` object where code is executed.

Comment: @AntiDrondert
Yes that worked for me, thank you so much

Comment: Tangentially -- you seldom need to use things like `Activate` and `Select` in well-written VBA. You don't need to activate a workbook to work with it.